# BASH Multiple on-exit functions for different exit levels

Tags: bash, sh

How can I use multiple on-exit traps in bash?
say i want to run on-exit-1 on exit code 1
and on-exit-2 on exit code 2

```
    function on-exit1 {
        echo "do stuff here if code had exit status 1"
        }
    function on-exit2 {
        echo "do stuff here if code had exit status 2"
        }
    .....

    trap on-exit1 EXIT # <--- what do i do here to specify the exit code to trap
    trap on-exit2 EXIT # <--- what do i do here to specify the exit code to trap
    .....
    some bashing up in here
    blah...blah
        exit 1 # do on-exit1
    else blah blah
        exit 2 # do on-exit2
    else blah blah
        exit N # do on-exitNth
```

Comment: Why are you trapping on exit, just exit in the functions and call them instead of exiting?

Comment: Either do something like @123 mentioned or define one exit function and check `$?` for the exitcode.

Comment: Something like `trap exit_check EXIT` with `exit_check () { status="$?"; [ "$status" -eq 1 ] && on_exit1 && return 0 ; [ "$status" -eq 2 ] && on_exit2 && return 0; } `

Comment: facepalm moment, you are right should have thought about that...my brain is a bit fried atm.
please @Aserre post yours as an answer (cuz you gave code aswell) so i can mark it as an answer although 123 is spot on aswell. thx guys...i need coffee

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following code sample should work :

```
exit_check () {
    # bash variable $? contains the last function exit code
    # will run the function on_exit1 if status exit is 1, on_exit2 if status exit is 2, ...
    on_exit$?
}
trap exit_check EXIT
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use Traps, try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function finish {
  echo "exitcode: $?"
}

trap finish EXIT

read -n 1 -s exitcode
exit $exitcode
```

But as @123 suggested, you could just call your exit functions, no need to 'abuse' Traps here.

Try to provide working a working example next time ;).